# Pass a value from HTML page to xquery

Tags: html, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am trying to delete a database by passing database name from a HTML page. 
Code is as follows:

HTML page:

```
<html>
  <body background="db.jpg">
    <form action="/database-delete" method="post">
      <div>
        <label for="database name">enter database name to delete:</label>
        <input type="text" id="database name" />
      </div>


    <form name="test" action="deleteDB.xqy?uid={xdmp:random()}" method="post"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <p><input type="submit" value="Delete a database"/></p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and XQuery is:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

declare variable $dbname as xs:string external;
let $config := admin:get-configuration()
let $result:= admin:database-exists($config, $dbname)
return
  if ($result) then
    (:--:)
    ( 
      "database deleted successfully",
      admin:save-configuration(
        admin:database-delete($config, admin:database-get-id($config,$dbname)))
    )
  else (
    "No such database exists..Please enter a valid input"
  )
```

But I am not able to do it. Please help me out. Thanks in advance....

Comment: are there two <form> elements on purpose?

Comment: Dave,
First form will just ask for DB name, where user will enter the DB name 
and in second form a submit button will appear ,clicking on which that module will be called by passing the entered DB name....

is it the right way..?

Answer (score 4):

To get a form value that was passed to MarkLogic, call [xdmp:get-request-field()](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:get-request-field).

Comment: So your exact line would look like: `declare variable $dbname as xs:string := xdmp:get-request-field("database_name");`.  Dave was right.